# C++ Accessing namespace members through function argument?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Looking for a solution for the following problem.
Two different namespace have the same member names (more than 1000 members). Is it possible to use a function of somesort to decide which namespace and which member to read to?

for example:

```
namespace a{
    uint8_t x = 10;
    uint8_t y = 1;
    uint8_t z 
    ...
    ...
    ...
}


namespace b{
    uint8_t x = 20;
    uint8_t y = 2;
    uint8_t z 
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass in the member's "name" as a parameter

```
uint8_t decide(int select_namespace, member_to_select){
    uint8_t ret_val = 0;
    if (select_namespace){
        ret_val = a::member_to_select;
    }else{
        ret_val = b::member_to_select;
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go, I'm sure someone can come up with another solution

You can use std::map and use the names as keys or indices in it. for example you would need to create a `map<char, uint8_t> members` and then you can assign values in it such as `members['x'] = 10`, you can access it by just passing in the name to the function as a parameter and inside the function it would look like `a::members[member_to_select]`
You will need to `#include <map>`

Again, probably not the ideal or even close to a good solution, someone else might be able to come up with a better one

Comment: That's not supported by C++, you need to work around by some means. You might try by array of pointers, and provide an enum representing the appropriate indices. If you can modify, then replace the namespaces by two structs. Then you can select the right struct easily and do member access afterwards: `decide(42).member_to_select`.